# How to get online users using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am connecting each users using the following code

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('join', function (username) {
            socket.join(username);
});
```

I want to get the users who are online and identify them.How it is possible.

Comment: You have to store each `socket` somewhere. Each single socket is another connection.

Comment: @JensWirth please give example link or something